# WebDriver - Python - How many elements in a drop-down menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i try to count how many element have a drop-down menu. Part of my code is :

```
while a < ? :

    Select(driver.find_element_by_id("MyBox")).select_by_index(a)

    a += 1
```

Other option is to check by index if element exists, but i'm not able to found the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`.options`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.options) attribute:

> `options`
>
> Returns a list of all options belonging to this select tag

```
 select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("MyBox"))
 print(len(select.options))
```