# WebDriver - Python - How many elements in a table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I grab text from some elements on a table (TableExemple) with Selenium :

```
 element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[2]/td").text
 element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[3]/td").text
 element3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[4]/td").text
 element4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("////table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[5]/td").text
```

In some cases, only element1 is present on the table.

How to check if others elements exist, to avoid error?

It´s possible to count how many elements have the table ( like  .options attribute for a drop-down menu : [WebDriver - Python - How many elements in a drop-down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454606/webdriver-python-how-many-elements-in-a-drop-down-menu))?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) to find multiple elements and call `len()` on the result:

```
cells = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[position() > 1]/td")
print(len(cells))
```

---

> How to check if others elements exist, to avoid error?

You can catch [`NoSuchElementException`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) being raised by `find_element_by_xpath()`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[2]/td").text
    element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[3]/td").text
    element3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[4]/td").text
    element4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='TableExemple']/tbody/tr[5]/td").text
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print "Element Not Found", e
```

Comment: Very complete answer; it works like a charm! thank you @alecxe

Answer (score 1):

I've found it best to first do something like:

```
table_el = driver.find_elements_by_css('#TableExample')
```

I like css, second only to ID's. This use of find_elements doesn't throw an exception when it finds nothing (note the plural 'elements')  Then with that returned list, possibly empty, go through the 'tr' elements:

```
if len(table_el.find_elements_by_css('tr')) < 1:
    return False  # or something more useful
trlist = list()
for tr in table_el.find_elements_by_css('tr'):
    trlist.append(tr)
```

Comment: And I thought we were both very helpful! :)

Comment: Agreed, +1 to you for it :)

Comment: Nice use of exceptions, especially for not just catching the generic type 'Exception' Upvote to you, too.